# Pull data from excel file on SharePoint 2016 using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

I am trying to use several files saved in a SharePoint 2016 site as data sources and pull info from those into a roll-up excel worksheet also on the SharePoint site. I am not sure what to use? I have tried opening the files and accessing them through normally ways with just the path updated but I think it might be a security issue?

Anyone out there doing this and have any thoughts?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this, but I used a SharePoint list as my data source, exported it to Excel (which creates a refreshable connection to the list), and then put the Excel file in one of my libraries.  I can then open the Excel file from there and refresh the connection.  However, in 2016 you will need to select Edit Workbook/Edit in Excel.  The Edit in Browser doesn't give me that capability.  At least not in my companies' setup for SharePoint.

You don't have to recreate your data as a list if you already have in Excel.  You can create a list then copy or import your spreadsheet into the list.  You will probably have to massage it some, but if you have much data it's probably quicker than retyping the data.

I'm not sure how you are pulling data from several data sources, but you can export all of your data sources individually, combine the sheets into one file, and then organize the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file you want to open in the actual app (it doesn't work if you open  just view mode), click on Menu File> Info> Copy Path.
Once you copy it, use it as a variable. This is what I use:

```vb
    Sub Open_SharePoint_File()
    
    Dim DrawFile as Workbook
    
    Dim BankData as String
    
    MyFileName = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/FOLDER/Shared%20Documents/yourfilename.xls?web=1"
        
            If MyFileName <> Empty And MyFileName <> "False" Then
                Set DrawFile = Application.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)
                Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
    
    End Sub
```